# Why is only the top half of my website responsive?

Tags: html, css

Why is it that the top half of my website (`header-wrapper` and `menu-wrapper`) is responsive, but the bottom (`featured-wrapper` and `footer`) isn't?

Recently, I've noticed that this responsive website behaves strangely when the screen is smaller than about `1000px`. The header and navigation menu shrink to fit the screen size, but the content wrapper, called `#featured-wrapper`, and `footer` don't. The content is cut off, and where they cut off they are replaced with a dark charcoal colored bar that is the same as the footer color. When the website is viewed in a larger browser it centers perfectly.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header-wrapper">
<div id="header" class="container">
<a href=""></a>
<h1></h1>
<br>
<h2></h2>
</div>
</div>
<div id="menu-wrapper">
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>
<!-- content -->
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="featured-wrapper">
<div class="extra2 container">
<div class="ebox1">
</div>
<div class="title">
<!-- content -->
</div>  
</div>  
</div>
</div>
<footer>
<div id="copyright" class="container">
<p></p>
</div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS for `#featured-wrapper` is:

```
#featured-wrapper
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10em 0em;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css specifies

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    ...
}
```

which is used in both the footer and the main content. One possible fix to this is to change it to

```
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    ...
}
```

so that it will stretch to the width of its parent but will never go larger than 1200px wide.

Comment: Thank you joshhunt, this worked perfectly for me. Adding those three little letters removed the charcoal bar on the side. :)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because of this css:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This prevents the `#featured-wrapper` element to show the slide bars:

[CSS overflow Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

> > The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.
> >     `hidden` The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible